# Infinite Scroll Memory Optimization Problem

Tags: optimization, memory, infinite-scroll

In one of my projects, we are applying infinite scroll for our site and as you can imagine after scrolling 100 hundred pages, the scrolling starts to slow down and the memory usage is huge. To fix it we decided that after 20 pages we start to delete other pages from the top. Basically, the document only contains a 20-page cell totally. But after this trial, we observe that still we have a huge amount of memory footprint. By the way, on every page, we have ads that coming from google.

> 100 page scroll with limit 20-page : 800 K memory  |||
> 100 page scroll with no limit : Still 800 K memory

We try to stop `googleadservice.refresh()` method and after that the memory footprint drops quite strong.
But stopping refresh means no ads at all.

Is there any way or idea for it?

Comment: How did you determine memory footprint? I'd assume that it's "not garbage collected (yet)" memory that isn't even been used; and that there's nothing you can do about it.

Comment: I'm checking it via Task Manager in Chrome. You can monitor it via Shift + ESC.

Comment: have you found a solution?